# Which JVM languages are interpreted rather than compiled to bytecode?

Tags: jvm-languages

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) on JVM languages states:

> Some of these languages are
>   interpreted by a Java program, and
>   some are compiled to Java bytecode...

Which well-known, general purpose JVM languages are interpreted by a Java program?

Comment: I don't think that statement is correct. A language with a Java interpreter is not a "JVM language", it's just an interpreted language. IMO a JVM language (which is in fact a misnomer, they'd be languages with a JVM implementation) is one that gets compiled to JVM bytecode

Comment: @cthom06 - I think your answer is actually the correct one. Please consider adding an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Zac - I still think cthom06's point is correct. The whole reason I asked the question is because the Wiki statement didn't sit right with me and wanted a second opinion. Your answer was helpful as well, however, so I upvoted it an encourage anyone reading this to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposted as answer:

I don't think that statement is correct. A language with a Java interpreter is not a "JVM language", it's just an interpreted language. IMO a JVM language (which is in fact a misnomer, they'd be languages with a JVM implementation) is one that gets compiled to JVM bytecode

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla Rhino (the Java javascript engine) is interpreted.

JRuby, Jython, and Scala are examples that are mostly compiled to bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the article is referring to languages like [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) or [Jython](http://www.jython.org)...

Comment: IINM, Jython does produce jvm bytecode (with an optional output of java source). It isn't really run over an interpreter written in Java (which is what I think the OP wants).

Answer (score 0):

Well Groovy for one is not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Another JVM language [SnapScript](https://github.com/snapscript/snap) is interpreted so that it can be run on Dalvik and ART (Android) in addition to the standard JRE.